# Spring Pageable PageRequest order by doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pagination, datatables, paging

I use spring pageable for pagination.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<Node> getPageableList(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageNumber, 15, Sort.Direction.DESC, "idNode");
    return nodeRepository.getNodesByPage(pageRequest);
}
```

As you can see , I want to sort my list by "idNode". But still my list sorted by name. I use jquery datatable. Maybe it change in client side my sorting. How I can solve it ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see in your screenshot, it's sorted by id and not the name!

Comment: No it sorted by name.In my table names are generated codes. These are not idNodes.